# urlfilter.ini for Opera Mini

Tags: opera-mini, opera-browser

For Opera or Opera Mobile it's possible to **block certain URLs** by adding a file **urlfilter.ini** to the user profiles. On Opera Mobile this file would be placed at `/data/data/com.opera.browser/opera/profiles/smartphone/urlfilter.ini`.

But this approach only seems to work for Opera Mobile, not Opera Mini. Is there a way to block certain URLs in **Opera Mini** so that the normal user can't change it via the Opera UI?

Another idea I had (my app runs on rooted devices with secured su access) but which wouldn't entire cover all my requirements:
Modifying the `/etc/hosts` file and change all urls to 127.0.0.1 - but the problem is that I don't just filter entire domains, but also just certain suffixes, etc. *.apk, and `/etc/hosts` doesn't allow wild cards just for file suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this line of thinking would work. The Opera Mini experience is built on the premise of the client being able to connect to Opera's rendering server farms and having a web page that's optimised for mobile view being sent to your phone/device after being compressed in order to save data network costs.

I don't think modifying your hosts file would work on Opera Mini - Mobile and your default browser - yes, because they connect directly from your phone to the page you're trying to view.

Comment: and it probably won't work on Opera Mobile with Opera Turbo as well.

Comment: +1 With Opera Mini the page isn't built on your phone, it's built on the server, so blocking URLs of adverts etc on your phone won't do anything, they need to be blocked on the server, which would affect everyone, so isn't in your control.